# knockout click binding - block binding on all elements except clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have question about click binding in knockout. I almost find solution but is still not that what I want. I using template for two lists (template is same). On a list I have few elements with this same binding, on start I can click on any button, but when I clicked on some element I want to block the ability to select / click on other items from only one list. example will be better to explain:
JS

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.people = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Bert', bio: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' },
        { name: 'Charles', bio: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' },
        { name: 'Denise', bio: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' }
    ]);
    self.workers = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Bart', bio: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' },
        { name: 'Joey', bio: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' },
        { name: 'Daniel', bio: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' }
    ]);
    self.checkVoice = function() {
      console.log('test');
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

HTML

```
<h2>List one</h2>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person', data: people }"></div>
<h2>List two</h2>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person', data: workers }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="person">
    <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
    <div data-bind="text: $data.name"></div>
    <button data-bind="click: $root.checkVoice">like</button>
    <button data-bind="click: $root.checkVoice">dislike</button>
    <!-- /ko --> 
</script>
```

[link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odygrxt8/2/)

My gol is: when I click on like button by "Bert" name I want to turn off possibility of clicks rest buttons in this one list, but I want to have possibility to exactly this same on second list.
This is possible to do using only one template?
Now I have something like this:

```
data-bind="click: function(data, event, type) { if(buttonClickedObservable()) { $root.checkAvailability($data, event, 'standard'); } }"
```

this solution is not bad but turning off possibility to click on both list not only on one

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding your requirements. but maybe a component instead of a template might suit your needs better. with a component you get a template and a viewmodel.

here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/odygrxt8/4/

again I did not quite understand your requirements about disabling buttons,  but if you run the fiddle only one like or dislike is active in any given list.

here is the component you may need to change the logic to fit your actual requirement but hopefully it will give you an idea.

```
ko.components.register('like-widget', {
  viewModel: function(params) {
    var self = this;
    this.data = params.value;
    this.selectedName = ko.observable('');
    this.choice = ko.observable('');
    this.likeIt = function(row) {
      self.selectedName(row.name);
      self.choice('like');
    };
    this.dislikeIt = function(row) {
      self.selectedName(row.name);
      self.choice('dislike');
    };
  },
  template: ' <div data-bind="foreach: data">\
           <div data-bind="text: $data.name"></div>\
            <button data-bind="click: $parent.likeIt, css: {\'btn-danger\': ($data.name == $parent.selectedName() && $parent.choice() == \'like\')}" class="btn">like</button>\
             <button data-bind="click: $parent.dislikeIt, css: {\'btn-warning\': ($data.name == $parent.selectedName() && $parent.choice() == \'dislike\')}" class="btn">Dislike</button>\
         </div>'
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan, this is a little helpful. I'll try to explain why I need to block button. In my project I have to lists like example in airlines first list is using to travel in one way, second list is using to return way if exist. For a one way and return way i using this same template write in script tag (this in necessary). List show you a tickets on selected day, example 10 results. One result have 3 classes economy, business and first. User can select only one class from all results. When click on button function connected to click bind check availability of this ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option for accomplishing this using a custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.groupClick = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var accessor = valueAccessor();
    var groupKey = allBindings().groupKey;    
    groupKey._groupClicked = groupKey._groupClicked || ko.observable(false);

    $(element).click(function(){
        groupKey._groupClicked(true);
    });

    var canClick = ko.computed(function(){
        return !groupKey._groupClicked();
    });
    var fontColor = ko.computed(function(){
        return { color: canClick() ? 'black' : 'silver' };
    });
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { enable: canClick, style: fontColor });
  }
}
```

The binding uses a "group" to keep track of which buttons share the same state, and in this case that group is the parent array. The binding then attaches an observable to the parent array to store the state and binds all elements in the same group array to that observable.

```js
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.people = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Bert', bio: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' },
        { name: 'Charles', bio: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' },
        { name: 'Denise', bio: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' }
    ]);
    self.workers = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Bart', bio: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' },
        { name: 'Joey', bio: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' },
        { name: 'Daniel', bio: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' }
    ]);
    self.checkVoice = function() {
      console.log('test');
    };
}

ko.bindingHandlers.groupClick = {
 init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
   var accessor = valueAccessor();
    var groupKey = allBindings().groupKey;    
    groupKey._groupClicked = groupKey._groupClicked || ko.observable(false);
    
    $(element).click(function(){
     groupKey._groupClicked(true);
    });
    
    var canClick = ko.computed(function(){
     return !groupKey._groupClicked();
    });
    var fontColor = ko.computed(function(){
     return { color: canClick() ? 'black' : 'silver' };
    });
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { enable: canClick, style: fontColor });
  }
}
 
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>List one</h2>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person', data: people }"></div>
<h2>List two</h2>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person', data: workers }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="person">
    <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
    <div data-bind="text: $data.name"></div>
    <button data-bind="groupClick: $root.checkVoice, groupKey: $parent">like</button>
    <button data-bind="groupClick: $root.checkVoice, groupKey: $parent">dislike</button>
    <!-- /ko --> 
</script>
```

```
<script type="text/html" id="person">
    <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
    <div data-bind="text: $data.name"></div>
    <button data-bind="groupClick: $root.checkVoice, groupKey: $parent">like</button>
    <button data-bind="groupClick: $root.checkVoice, groupKey: $parent">dislike</button>
    <!-- /ko --> 
</script>
```